# Showing duplicate row: new Android 4.1 + Jquerymobile + Phonegap 1.8

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I was using Android 4.0.3+JQM+Phonegap without having troubles. Yesterday I tested on Android 4.1 and found that those dynamically generated ListView would sometimes give me duplicated results. For example, I use the following code to generate a ListView to show today's date:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c" 
data-divider-theme="d" id="todayvalue">             
</ul>


document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
var today = new Date();
var dayofmonth = today.getDate();
var dayofweek = today.getDay();
var year = today.getFullYear();
var month = today.getMonth();
var myDays=      ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"];
var m_names = ["January", "February", "March", 
    "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", 
    "October", "November", "December"];
$('#todayvalue').append('<li>Today is '+ myDays[dayofweek]+ ', '+year+'-'+m_names[month]+'-'+dayofmonth+'</li>');
$('#todayvalue').listview('refresh');


 }
```

It used to have no problem at all. But now it would generate two identical rows.

Whom to blame?

Update: I have uploaded the project to https://github.com/ysongfinance/520Toll.

After further debugging, I found that **onDeviceReady() was called twice** but one of them looks weird:

07-05 20:42:31.368: I/Web Console(825): ########in OndeviceReady at file:///android_asset/www/js/updatetoll.js:4
07-05 20:42:31.488: I/Web Console(825): ########in OndeviceReady **at null**:4

Look at the second call "in OndeviceReady at null", what does that "null" suppose to mean?

Comment: try  pagecreate or pageinit instead of deviceready. Look under 'page initialization events'. http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/events.html

Comment: how does that help? I still need the method to work after deviceready is fired.

Comment: the easier way would be to put some to log and see whether `deviceready` is being called multiple times or only once. also you can use the http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/ to debug the generated page

Comment: As it turned out, onDeviceReady() was called multiple times.

Comment: put your `<script src="js/updatetoll.js"></script>` in the `<head>` tag and it fires only once, i will post the answer with solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your example with Cordova 1.9 and Android 2.2 and it was firing `deviceready` twice.

Then I moved the `updatetoll.js` included in body to head and it fires only once.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>520 Toll Rate</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" /> 

        <script src="js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script> 
        <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova-1.9.0.js"></script>
        <script src="js/updatetoll.js"></script>        
    </head>
    <body>      
        <div data-role="header">                
                <img src="logo/ic520toll.png" width=50px height=50px style="margin-left: 40%;"">            
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c" 
            data-divider-theme="d" id="todayvalue">             
        </ul>           

        </div>  

    </body>
</html>
```

Can you check this change and see does it work in your device.

### Edit

jQuery Mobile seems to create the problem if you put the listener outside of the `head` tag. I tried the newer version of jQuery Mobile (1.1.0) but the affect is still the same.

If you remove the jQuery Mobile and keep your code as it is then it will fire only once.

Comment: thanks I figured it out anyway. I'm using a flag inside onDeviceReady to make sure it was called exactly once. I guess your solution also works.